# Secure JSON Request via Alamofire and Self-Signed Certificates

Tags: ios, json, swift, ssl, certificate

I want my swift app allow to send the https request on node.js and then postgre in order to avoid the "man in the middle.
1. From browser it works fine.
2. From local Mac OS it works fine.
3. But from iOS App it doesn't works at all - error **9843**

Swift Code:

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire

class NetworkManager {
    static let sharedInstance = NetworkManager()

    let manager: Alamofire.SessionManager = {
        let serverTrustPolicies: [String: ServerTrustPolicy] = [
            "https://sensemp.ru:51342/employee/req": .pinCertificates(
                certificates: ServerTrustPolicy.certificates(),
                validateCertificateChain: true,
                validateHost: true),
            "sensemp.ru:51342/employee/req": .disableEvaluation
        ]

        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders = Alamofire.SessionManager.defaultHTTPHeaders

        return Alamofire.SessionManager(
            configuration: configuration,
            serverTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: serverTrustPolicies)
        )
    }()
}
```

And View Controller:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

//...
NetworkManager.sharedInstance.manager.request("https://sensemp.ru:51342/employee/req", method: .get).responseJSON{ response in
        switch response.result {
                        case .success(let value):
                            let json = JSON(value)
                            print("JSON: \(json)")
                        case .failure(let error):
                            print(error)
                        }

}
}
```

Problem is that with a self signed certificate.

```
    2020-05-06 22:21:21.256942+0300 AlamofireExample[32310:690636] Connection 1: default TLS Trust evaluation failed(-9843)
2020-05-06 22:21:21.257176+0300 AlamofireExample[32310:690636] Connection 1: TLS Trust encountered error 3:-9843
2020-05-06 22:21:21.257331+0300 AlamofireExample[32310:690636] Connection 1: encountered error(3:-9843)
```

[image: Added self-signed certificate into simulator]

What Apple writes about that

[image: problem with sertificate]
[image: error]

What is wrong with my self-signed certificate?

[image]

Found same case and answer from apple developer team:

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/42555

So TLSTool **./TLSTool s_client -connect sensemp.ru:51342** says me:

- input stream did open
- output stream did open
- output stream has space
- protocol: TLS 1.2
- cipher: ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
- trust result: proceed
- certificate info:
- 0 + rsaEncryption 2048 sha256-with-rsa-signature 'sensemp.ru'

How fix that issue?

P.S.: Mac OS Catalina 10.15.4 | iOS 13.4.1 | nginx/1.17.9 | PostgreSQL 12 | SSL

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let manager: Alamofire.SessionManager = {
        let serverTrustPolicies: [String: ServerTrustPolicy] = [
            "https://sensemp.ru": .pinCertificates(
                certificates: ServerTrustPolicy.certificates(),
                validateCertificateChain: true,
                validateHost: true),
            "sensemp.ru": .disableEvaluation
        ]
```

- add ip from hosts into certificate DNS section

[image]